# DSolve solves PDE only without boundary condition, but fails otherwise

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve for `Te[w, Pprobe, t]` in a partial differential equation. What's surprising is that it manages to solve it when I don't put in any initial conditions. But when I put in `Te[w, Pprobe, 0] == 0.3` it doesn't work:

```
C1 = 10^-10;
C2 = 0.1*C1;
R = 50;
Tb = 0.1;
Geb = 5*10^-15;
Z0 = 50;
L[Te_] := 10^-9 + 10^-9*(Te - 0.1);
Zlcr[Te_, w_] := (1/R + 1/(I*L[Te]*w) + I*C1*w)^-1;
Zload[Te_, w_] := -I*w*C2 + Zlcr[Te, w];
Γ[Te_, w_] := (Zload[Te, w] - Z0)/(Zload[Te, w] + Z0);
y[Te_, w_] := (Abs[Γ[Te, w]])^2;
p[Te_, w_] := Abs[Γ[Te, w]]
Co = 10^-35;
Vol = 10^-21;
Cv = Co/Vol;
Te0 = 0.3;

pde = 
  Cv*D[Te[w, Pprobe, t], t] == 
    -Geb (Te[w, Pprobe, t] - Tb) + (1 - y[Te[w, Pprobe, t], w])*Pprobe

soln = 
  Te[w, Pprobe, t] /. 
    First @ DSolve[{pde, Te[w, Pprobe, 0] == 0.3}, Te[w, Pprobe, t], {w, Pprobe, t}]
```

Comment: This is not surprising, examine this post [Solving a differential equation with initial conditions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45470/solving-a-differential-equation-with-initial-conditions/45471#45471). Boundary conditions can be inconsistent with certain differential equations. If you use `DSolve` you should deal with exact numbers instead of machine precission ones see e.g. this post [No result from DSolve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13210/no-result-from-dsolve/13212#13212).

Comment: The trick the first link uses is to manually specify the constants of integration. I'm afraid it doesn't work here, as the result is a very complicated function where I don't know what the constants are. That's why I'm trying to specify the initial condition first

Comment: It might be also due to that $Te(0)$ is undefined in the integrand, so now I'm trying $Te(0.1) = 0.3$, I've run the code and I'll post an update as soon as it's finished

Comment: That didn't work, so I solved it in the general form, which looks complicated