# DSolve not finding solution I expected

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, warning-messages

Try to solve the following ODE via `DSolve`

$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
 y'(x)+2 y(x) e^x-y(x)^2 &= e^{2 x}+e^x \\
 y'(0) &=1
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

The expected solution is $y(x)=e^x$, but *Mathematica* produces the message:

> DSolve::bvfail: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution

**Note:** $y(x)=e^x$ is obviously a special solution to the original ODE and satisfies the initial/boundary value condition which can be easily verified by substituting it into the ODE.

Additionally, it is easy to deduct that: $y'(0)=1\Leftrightarrow y(0)=1$ for this ODE;

How to handle it?

Comment: I see no reason to worry. There is no problem in letting the constant of Integration C[1] go to infinity. Infinity is just one point in the complex plane. Then the general solution collapses into the "expected" simple exponential.

Comment: The command of Maple 2018 `dsolve({diff(y(x), x)+2*y(x)*exp(x)-y(x)^2 = exp(2*x)+exp(x), (D(y))(0) = 1}, y(x))` performs `y(x) = exp(x)`.

Comment: this differential equation is artificial or it comes from some modelling problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### The problem - Genericity of solutions

The problem we encounter here is that `DSolve` can return only a **generic solution** however that general solution cannot satisfy such an initial condition as `y'[0] == 1`. The issue is related to an **arbitrary** choice of **constants of integration** i.e. such constants that are specific to certain types of a differential equations `DSolve` tries to solve during the integration process.

```
DSolve[{y'[x] + 2 E^x y[x] - y[x]^2 == E^(2 x) + E^x, y'[0] == 1}, y[x], x]
```

> ```
> DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions 
>  lead to an empty solution. >>
>
> {}
> ```

Solving the ODE without the initial condition we will see that the general solution excludes exceptional ones:

```
y[x_, c_] = y[x] /. First @ DSolve[{ y'[x] + 2 E^x y[x] - y[x]^2 == E^(2 x) + E^x},
                                    y[x], x] /. C[1] -> c
```

> ```
>  E^x + 1/(c - x)
> ```

Namely there is no constant `c` reducing the general solution to `E^x` however putting e.g. `y'[0] == 2` we will find a solution:

```
DSolve[{y'[x] + 2 E^x y[x] - y[x]^2 == E^(2 x) + E^x, y'[0] == 2}, y[x], x]// First
```

> ```
>  {y[x] -> (-1 - E^x + E^x x)/(-1 + x)}
> ```

This is quite similar issue to one we can find here: [Solving a differential equation with initial conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45470/solving-a-differential-equation-with-initial-conditions).

The problem cannot be fixed changing the variables in the ODE to :

```
y'[x] + 2 E^x y[x] - y[x]^2 == E^(2 x) + E^x /. 
{y[x] -> z[x] + E^x, y'[x] -> z'[x] + E^x} // Simplify
```

> ```
> z[x]^2 == z'[x]
> ```

```
DSolve[{z'[x] == z[x]^2, z'[0] == 0}, z[x], x]
```

> ```
> DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions 
> lead to an empty solution. >>
>
> {}
> ```

### Remedy

Introducing an initial condition in a general symbolic way we can find also the special solution:

```
f[x_, c_] = z[x] /. DSolve[{z'[x] == z[x]^2, z'[0] == c}, z[x], x]
```

> ```
>  { -(Sqrt[c]/(-1 + Sqrt[c] x)), -(Sqrt[c]/(1 + Sqrt[c] x))}
> ```

```
f[x, c] /. Solve[D[f[x, c] == 0], c]
```

> ```
> { 0, 0}
> ```

I.e. we get the special solution `y[x] == E^x`.

we can see that the same trick can work also in the original equation.

Alternatively the general solution can be reparametrized in a different way:

```
E^x + c/(1 - x)
```

yields also the special solution although this excludes e.g. `E^x - 1/x`

Comment: Can we know how the `DSolve` works? Is the general solution, $y(x)=e^x+\dfrac{1}{c-x}$, correct? Since $y(x)=e^x$ is obviously a special solution to the ODE, which can be easily verified.

Comment: I mean since $y(x)=e^x$ is a special solution to the ODE, then the ODE with initial condition is not incompatible and the current solving approach `DSolve` uses may be inappropriate.

Comment: You get the special solution $e^x$ by taking the limit $c \rightarrow \infty$ of the general solution $e^x+\frac{1}{c-x}$.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell This is a useful observation however the problem that `DSolve` yields generic solutions remains.

Answer (score 9):

In V13.1, the new `DSolve` option `IncludeSingularSolutions -> True` yields the sought-after solution:

```
DSolve[{y'[x] + 2 E^x y[x] - y[x]^2 == E^(2 x) + E^x, y'[0] == 1}, 
 y[x], x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]
```

> DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution.
>
> DSolve::bvnr: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions do not restrict the existing freedom in the general solution.

> ```
> (*  {{y[x] -> E^x}}  *)
> ```

Comment: Nice! And you mean V13.1.

Comment: @GregHurst Thanks, I thought I did, but when I checked the documentation for `DSolve`, the last update indicated is V13.0 and no "show changes" button. So I thought I was probably wrong. In my uncertainty, I wrote V13 and left off the minor number. (Actually, randomly checking "updated" commands in "Summary of New Features in 13.1," I see that `DSolve` is not alone in having mixed messages.)

Answer (score 5):

Quite often a differential equation may be viewed as an algebraic problem.  In such a view, the integration constant `C[1]` might naturally be viewed as an element of the projective line.  But in the natural *Mathematica* point of view, the constant is taken to belong to an affine subspace, namely the real number line.  One could approach finding a solution by taking `C[1]` to belong to the projective space, via `C[1] -> a/b`, or by taking it to belong to a different affine subspace, say via `C[1] -> 1/C[1]`.

In both approaches below, we solve the general differential equation, remap `C[1]`, and solve the boundary condition for `C[1]`.

Here is an approach via the projective line, replacing `C[1]` by the ratio `a/b`.  A potential pitfall here is that `a` and `b` are defined only up to a constant of proportionality, but it turns out `Solve` can handle it in this case.

```
ysol = First @ DSolve[{y'[x] + 2 E^x y[x] - y[x]^2 == E^(2 x) + E^x}, y[x], x] /.
  C[1] -> a/b // Simplify
Solve[D[y[x] /. ysol, x] == 1 /. x -> 0, {a, b}]
ysol /. First[%]

(*
  {y[x] -> E^x + b/(a - b x)}

  Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
  {{b -> 0}}

  {y[x] -> E^x}
*)
```

A better way perhaps is to take a different affine subspace by moving some finite point to infinity.  The replacement `C[1] -> 1/C[1]` moves `0` to infinity (so we lose the solution where the original `C[1] == 0`).  In this formulation there is just one constant to solve for, and at least in this case `Solve` gets the multiplicity right.

```
ysol = First @ DSolve[{y'[x] + 2 E^x y[x] - y[x]^2 == E^(2 x) + E^x}, y[x], x] /.
  C[1] -> 1/C[1] // Together
Solve[D[y[x] /. ysol, x] == 1 /. x -> 0, C[1]]
ysol /. First[%]

(*
  {y[x] -> (-E^x - C[1] + E^x x C[1])/(-1 + x C[1])}

  {{C[1] -> 0}, {C[1] -> 0}}

  {y[x] -> E^x}
*)
```

*Update -- General solution comprising all solutions*

If we take an even less familiar route and move a non-real, complex number, such as `I`, to infinity, we can get the solution(s) for all valid initial (real) values for `y'[x]`, which must be at least `1`.

```
ysol = First@ DSolve[{y'[x] + 2 E^x y[x] - y[x]^2 == E^(2 x) + E^x}, y[x], x] /.
  C[1] -> 1/(C[1] - I) // Together;
Csol = Solve[D[y[x] /. ysol, x] == c /. x -> 0, C[1]];
gensol = {y -> Function @@ #} & /@ Thread[{x, y[x] /. ysol /. Csol // Simplify}]

{y[0], y'[0]} /. gensol // Simplify               (* initial values *)

y[x] /. gensol /. c -> 1                          (* OP's desired solution *)

(*
  {{y -> Function[x, (-Sqrt[-1 + c] + E^x (1 + Sqrt[-1 + c] x))/(1 + Sqrt[-1 + c] x)]},
   {y -> Function[x, (Sqrt[-1 + c] + E^x - Sqrt[-1 + c] E^x x)/(1 - Sqrt[-1 + c] x)]}}

  {{1 - Sqrt[-1 + c], c}, {1 + Sqrt[-1 + c], c}}  (* initial values *)

  {E^x, E^x}                                      (* OP's desired solution *)
*)
```

Generically, there are two distinct solutions for each initial value for `y'[0]`, but they coincide for `y'[0] == 1`.

Answer (score 4):

An extended comment that is too long for the comment section.

Amplifying on the comment by Stephen Luttrell:

```
eqn = y'[x] + 2 E^x y[x] - y[x]^2 == E^(2 x) + E^x;
```

The generic solution

```
solnG = DSolve[eqn, y[x], x][[1, 1]]
```

> y[x] -> E^x + 1/(-x + C[1])

Verifying that the generic solution satisfies the equation

```
eqn /. NestList[D[#, x] &, solnG, 1] // Simplify
```

> True

Obtaining the special solution requested

```
solnS = (y[x] -> Limit[y[x] /. solnG, C[1] -> Infinity])
```

> y[x] -> E^x

As expected, the special solution satisfies the equation

```
eqn /. NestList[D[#, x] &, solnS, 1] // Simplify
```

> True

The requested boundary condition is inherent to the special solution

```
solnS /. x -> 0
```

> y[0] -> 1

Answer (score 4):

Another remedy is to take the limit as `y'[0] -> 1`:

```
sol = DSolve[{y'[x] + 2 E^x y[x] - y[x]^2 == E^(2 x) + E^x, y'[0] == a}, y[x], x];

Limit[y[x] /. sol, a -> 1]

(* {E^x, E^x} *)
```