# DSolve not returning "trivial" solutions

Tags: differential-equations

When I enter this

```
DSolve[y'[x]^2 + y[x]^2 == 1, y[x], x]
```

the answer I get is

```
{{y[x] -> -Sin[x - C[1]]}, {y[x] -> Sin[x + C[1]]}}
```

but the two functions $y(x)=1$ and $y(x)=-1$ which are also solutions to this differential equation aren't mentioned.  Is this an oversight or am I missing something?

Comment: This question is answered here [DSolve not finding solution I expected](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57910/dsolve-not-finding-solution-i-expected/57912#57912). The only difference is that there we had `z[x]^2 == z'[x]`. So it is just a duplicate.
`

Comment: @Artes Can you explicitly show how to get the non-general solutions in this case?

Comment: @TeakeNutma  The question is "Is this an oversight or am I missing something?" and the answer there is in the linked post. This is not "How do I get a special solution?" so I'm not going to play with it. Right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the case where the derivative is zero everywhere (which is not a differential equation), you can use

```
Join[
 DSolve[y'[x]^2 + y[x]^2 == 1, y[x], x],
 Solve[y[x]^2 == 1, y[x]]]
```

> {{y[x] -> -Sin[x - C[1]]}, {y[x] -> Sin[x + C[1]]}, {y[x] -> -1}, {y[x] -> 1}}

Although, DSolve does not complain about the lack of a derivative in the equation

```
Join[
 DSolve[y'[x]^2 + y[x]^2 == 1, y[x], x],
 DSolve[y[x]^2 == 1, y[x], x]]
```

> {{y[x] -> -Sin[x - C[1]]}, {y[x] -> Sin[x + C[1]]}, {y[x] -> -1}, {y[x] -> 1}}

```
% == %%
```

> True