# DSolve returns an answer that is not a solution

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

Investigating [DSolve misses a solution of a differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86152/dsolve-misses-a-solution-of-a-differential-equation/89385#89385), I came across this odd behavior of `DSolve`.

The following DSolve command returns an answer to the ODE but the solutions do not satisfy the differential equation.

```
F[x_, y_, p_] := 4 p + p^2 x^2 - 2 p x y + y^2;
dsol = DSolve[{F[x, y[x], y'[x] - 5] == 0, y[1] == 1}, y, x]
F[x, y[x], y'[x] - 5] /. dsol // FullSimplify
```

> `Solve::ifun`: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>   `Solve::svars`: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
>   `Solve::ifun`: ...
>   `Solve::svars`: ...
>   `DSolve::bvnr`: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions do not restrict the existing freedom in the general solution. >>
>   ...
>   `General::stop`: Further output of DSolve::bvnr will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

```
(*
{{y -> Function[{x}, -5 x - 2 Sqrt[5 - Log[E^K$84905]] + x Log[E^K$84905]]},
 {y -> Function[{x}, -5 x + 2 Sqrt[5 - Log[E^K$84905]] + x Log[E^K$84905]]},
 {y -> Function[{x}, -5 x - 2 Sqrt[5 - Log[E^K$86037]] + x Log[E^K$86037]]},
 {y -> Function[{x}, -5 x + 2 Sqrt[5 - Log[E^K$86037]] + x Log[E^K$86037]]}}

{-5 (4 - 5 x^2 + 4 x Sqrt[5 - Log[E^K$84905]]), 
 5 (-4 + 5 x^2 + 4 x Sqrt[5 - Log[E^K$84905]]),
 -5 (4 - 5 x^2 + 4 x Sqrt[5 - Log[E^K$86037]]), 
 5 (-4 + 5 x^2 + 4 x Sqrt[5 - Log[E^K$86037]])}
*)
```

Well, the ODE is singular along `y[x] == 1/x` (see linked question).
Maybe that has something to do with the `DSolve::bvnr` warning, and maybe we should try an initial condition located off the singular locus, but no luck. We even get the same answer:

```
DSolve[{F[x, y[x], y'[x] - 5] == 0, y[1] == 1/2}, y, x]
(* Same messages and result as above *)
```

Even asking for the general solution yields the same answer:

```
DSolve[{F[x, y[x], y'[x] - 5] == 0}, y, x]
(*
  Messages: Solve::ifun, Solve::svars but not DSolve::bvnr
  Same answer as above
*)
```

However a symbolic parameter results in an empty set.

```
dsol = DSolve[{F[x, y[x], y'[x] - a] == 0, y[1] == 1}, y, x]
(*  {}  *)
```

Following the advice of `Solve::ifun`, we can try using `Reduce` as the algebraic solver, and we get the empty solution:

```
With[{opts = Options[Solve]},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce],
  redsol = DSolve[{F[x, y[x], y'[x] - a] == 0, y[1] == 1}, y, x],
  SetOptions[Solve, opts]]]
```

> `DSolve::bvimp`: General solution contains implicit solutions. In the boundary value problem, these solutions will be ignored, so some of the solutions will be lost. >>

```
(*  {}  *)
```

Omitting the initial condition yields a "double-empty" solution `{{}, {}}`, which I've never seen before.

Questions:

- The first result seems wrong and a bug. Is there a relationship to the ODE I am overlooking?  Is it a bug?
- The first result also suggests `DSolve` found some sort of solution that got mangled on its way back to user-level.  If so, is there a way to coax it out of `DSolve`?
- The result with `Reduce` normally means the equation are inconsistent, which is not the case; might it mean `DSolve` cannot solve the ODE with its current methods, or is it bug?

Comment: Looking at the errors, it looks like a branch cut problem. Solvers in general  don't handle these kinds of branch cut problems very well. See this example: (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sqrt%5Bf%27%5Bx%5D%5D+%3D%3D+-x). This isn't really a bug as much as an expected hardship of computer algebra

Comment: @Searke, yes it does.  Here's a plot of some (numerical) solutions, if it's any help: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Aezaa.png

Comment: Put more simply. Do you consider this to be a bug?
DSolve[{Sqrt[f'[x]] == -x}, f[x], x]
{{f[x] -> x^3/3 + C[1]}}

Comment: @Searke No, *that* I expect.  (Indeed, I explain why in the linked question.)  But the behavior here is not the same in the following way.  Algebraically, your ODE is a branch of the rationalized DE `f'[x]^2 == x^2`, and the return value is a solution of the rationalized equation.  The return value in the question seems to have nothing to do with my ODE, which is already a polynomial (in `x`, `y`, `y'`).  (It almost certainly does, but the relationship is obscure.)

Comment: @MichaelE2  The solutions returned by `DSolve` are those that would be obtained from `Solve[F[x, y, K$ - 5] == 0, y]` and look nothing like the numerical solutions to this problem.  I would guess that `DSolve` crashed internally and returned what it happened to have last calculated.  Certainly, a bug.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Well spotted! Thank you very much.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Also, `fr = Solve[F[x, y[x], y'[x] - 5] == 0, y'[x]]; DSolve[{fr[[1, 1]] /. Rule -> Equal, y[1] == 1}, y, x] ` gives the same error messages and nonsense answers.