# How to simplify the $Sqrt$

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a expression:

```
13 + 6 Sqrt[6 - x] x == x
```

I want to simplify the `Sqrt` to be `-169+26 x+215 x^2-36 x^3==0`.But `Simplify[13 + 6 Sqrt[6 - x] x == x, Assumptions -> x < 6]` don't work.And I have tried `ComplexityFunction`:

```
FullSimplify[13 + 6 Sqrt[6 - x] x == x, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (1000 Count[#, _Sqrt, {0, Infinity}] + 
     LeafCount[#] &)]
```

I can get anything still.So how to elminate the `Sqrt`?

Comment: I don't understand. How did you obtain the second expression from the first? They don't seem to have the same solutions either.

Comment: @MarcoB Confused too.I just want elminate the `Sqrt`.I get it by `((x-13)/6x)^2+x-6==0//FullSimplify//Expand`

Comment: OK but that still didn't explain the relationship between the expression with the `Sqrt` and the equation you have in comments. How did you get from `((x - 13) / 6 x)^2 + x - 6 == 0` to `13 + 6 Sqrt[6 - x] x == x`?

Comment: @MarcoB Move ` x - 6` to right of the equal sign,then execute sqrt...and so on

Comment: To be explicit, that expression is wrong. You probably meant `-169 + 26 x + 215 x^2 - 36 x^3 == 0`.

Comment: @Szabolcs How do you get it?

Comment: Square both sides of `6 Sqrt[6 - x] x == x - 13`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Do you think what wrong with `((x-13)/6x)^2+x-6==0//FullSimplify//Expand`?

Comment: It should be `(x-13)/(6x)`, not `(x-13)/6x`.

Comment: @Szabolcs God,stupid error.Thanks very much.

Comment: Could have happened to me too ... couldn't see it for quite a while.

Comment: @MarcoB Do you think [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138329/21532) is useless still?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps:

```
Solve[13 + 6 Sqrt[6 - x] x == x, x, Cubics -> False]
```

> {{x -> Root[169 - 26 #1 - 215 #1^2 + 36 #1^3 &, 1]}}

Comment: little wired. :)Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 3):

Adapting the `F` function from [DSolve misses a solution of a differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86152/dsolve-misses-a-solution-of-a-differential-equation/89385#89385), we get

```
Clear[rat];
(* rationalize fractional powers *)
rat[eqn_Equal] := rat[Subtract @@ eqn] == 0;
rat[fn_] := Module[{u}, 
   With[{rads = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[fn, Power[a_, b_Rational] :> u[a, b], Infinity]}, 
    First@GroebnerBasis[
      Flatten@{fn /. Power[a_, b_Rational] :> u[a, b], 
        Map[
         Numerator@Together[           (*gets rid of denominators in neg.powers*)
           #^Denominator[Last@#] - First[#]^Numerator[Last@#]
           ] &, 
         rads]}, rads]]];

rat[13 + 6 Sqrt[6 - x] x == x]

(* Out[79]= 169 - 26 x - 215 x^2 + 36 x^3 == 0 *)
```

Comment: Little long...;)

Comment: @yode I think you mean "too general." :)

Answer (score 0):

`GroebnerBasis` can do this:

```
First[GroebnerBasis[13 + 6 Sqrt[6 - x] x - x, x]]
```

> 169-26 x-215 x^2+36 x^3