Expansion of implicit function
Related (but not being solved) question: AsymptoticSolve for Taylor Expansion of Implicit Function
I have a implicit function defined as follow
$$
T = \frac{1}{4\pi M}\frac{\sqrt{M^2-(J/M)^2}}{M+\sqrt{M^2-(J/M)^2}}
$$
Where $J$ is a constant. And I want to get the expansion of $M$ w.r.t. $T$. Here is my tries:

First, I use the function AsymptoticSolve, but it seems that the equation is rather complicated and it doesn't work.
AsymptoticSolve[T == (m^2 - (J/m)^2)^(1/2)/(2*m*(m + (m^2 -(J/m)^2)^(1/2))), {m, Sqrt[J]}, {T, 0, 3}]


Because if I use a simpler equation
AsymptoticSolve[T == (m^2 - (J/m)^2), {m, Sqrt[J]}, {T, 0, 3}]

then it works:


Second, I want to do it indirectly by using ImplicitD , and it is just what I expected that the result will explicitly depend on $m$

ImplicitD[T == (m^2 - (J/m)^2)^(1/2)/(2*m*(m + (m^2 -(J/m)^2)^(1/2))), m,T] // FullSimplify



which is not good.
Are there any new methods that can be used to solve the problem? Thank you in advance for your help.
The answer is
$$
M = \sqrt{J} + 4 J^{3/2} π^2 T^2 + 32 J^2 π^3 T^3 + \dots
$$
See (2.4) in 2310.00848

If you post code instead of images, you might get (more) people to help you.

@Goofy Thanks for your advice Goofy! Codes added!

There's a typo in your code: (J^2/m)^2 instead of (J/m)^2.

@MichaelE2 I am so sorry for that, now the bug has been fixed

Thanks for updating with the code. I got AsymptoticSolve to work. I had to add some assumptions as well as rationalize. Sqrt can be tricky around its branch point, I guess. Not sure if this is a bug.

f[m_, j_] = 1/(4 π m) Sqrt[m^2 - (j/m)^2]/(m + Sqrt[m^2 - (j/m)^2]);

Solving $f(m,j)=t$ for $m$: the solutions are roots of a fifth-order polynomial,
Solve[f[m, j] == t, m]
(*    {{m -> Root[j^2 - 8 j^2 π t #1 + 16 j^2 π^2 t^2 #1^2 - #1^4 + 8 π t #1^5 &, 1]},
      {{m -> Root[j^2 - 8 j^2 π t #1 + 16 j^2 π^2 t^2 #1^2 - #1^4 + 8 π t #1^5 &, 2]},
      {{m -> Root[j^2 - 8 j^2 π t #1 + 16 j^2 π^2 t^2 #1^2 - #1^4 + 8 π t #1^5 &, 3]},
      {{m -> Root[j^2 - 8 j^2 π t #1 + 16 j^2 π^2 t^2 #1^2 - #1^4 + 8 π t #1^5 &, 4]},
      {{m -> Root[j^2 - 8 j^2 π t #1 + 16 j^2 π^2 t^2 #1^2 - #1^4 + 8 π t #1^5 &, 5]}    *)

Which one do we want? It turns out that root #2 is the one that goes to $\sqrt{j}$ as $t\to0$:
Series[Root[j^2 - 8 j^2 π t #1 + 16 j^2 π^2 t^2 #1^2 - #1^4 + 8 π t #1^5 &, 2], {t, 0, 3}]
(*    Sqrt[j] + 4 j^(3/2) π^2 t^2 + 32 j^2 π^3 t^3 + O[t]^4    *)


Wow, this is a fast way to do that! Thanks Roman! Maybe I should learn something about Root First

How do I work with Root objects?
tl;dr: a Root object is an exact representation that can be handled linke any other special function. For example, z = Root[#^3 + #^2 - 1 & , 1] is an exact number, with NumericQ[z] giving True and FullSimplify[z^3 + z^2] giving 1 (the exact integer, not a numerical approximation). ToRadicals[z] gives a more explicit expression that is only available up to fourth order.

If you rationalize the equation, AsymptoticSolve works.
I'll copy my code from the Q&A How to simplify the $Sqrt$ since it's closed and may be deleted.
(*https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138295*)
(*rationalize fractional powers*)
rat[eqn_Equal] := rat[Subtract @@ eqn] == 0;
rat[fn_] := Module[{u},
   With[{rads =
      DeleteDuplicates@
       Cases[fn, Power[a_, b_Rational] :> u[a, b], Infinity]},
    First@GroebnerBasis[
      Flatten@{
        fn /. Power[a_, b_Rational] :> u[a, b],
        Map[
         
         Numerator@
           Together[(*gets rid of denominators in neg.powers*)#^
              Denominator[Last@#] - First[#]^Numerator[Last@#]
            ] &,
         rads
         ]},
      rads]]];

eqn = T == (m^2 - (J^2/m)^2)^(1/2)/(4*Pi*
     m*(m + (m^2 - (J^2/m)^2)^(1/2)))
rat[eqn]

(* J^2/m^2 - m^2 - (4 J^2 T)/m + 4 m^3 T + 4 J^2 T^2 == 0 *)

AsymptoticSolve[rat[eqn], {m, Sqrt[J]}, {T, 0, 3}]

(* {{m -> Sqrt[J] + J^(3/2) T^2 + 4 J^2 T^3}} *)

I do not know whether this should be considered a bug or not. Rationalizing square roots seems like a thing after all. Whether that means the computer should be expected to try it or the user I'm not sure. Sometimes it's just wasting time.
P.S. Possible bug
The pre-AsymptoticSolve approach in the code below was going to be my answer, and it does seem to reveal a bug. Then I got my head out where it could see, and I remembered rationalizing was a thing, a thing I had used before.
In any case, the straight-forward attempt fails:
With[{ser = Series[T /. First@Solve[eqn, T], {m, Sqrt[J], 3}, 
    Assumptions -> m > Sqrt[J] > 0]},
 Assuming[J > 0,
  InverseSeries[ser, T]
  ]
 ]


SeriesData::scmp: The constant term of series T^2+O[T]^7 does not match the expansion point of Sqrt[m-Sqrt[J]]/J^(3/4)-(2 (m-Sqrt[J]))/J+(7 (m-Sqrt[J])^(3/2))/(4 J^(5/4))-(m-Sqrt[J])^2/J^(3/2)+(31 (m-Sqrt[J])^(5/2))/(32 J^(7/4))-(m-Sqrt[J])^3/J^2+O[m-Sqrt[J]]^(7/2).
(*InverseSeries[ComposeSeries[SeriesData[m, J^Rational[1, 2], {J^Rational[-3, 4], (-2)/J, Rational[7, 4] J^Rational[-5, 4], -J^Rational[-3, 2], Rational[31, 32] J^Rational[-7, 4], (-1) J^(-2)}, 1, 7, 2], SeriesData[T, 0, {1}, 2, 7, 1]]]^2*)

The problem is that the constant term was computed as 0 and not Sqrt[J].  That made me try translating m so that it starts at 0 and not Sqrt[J].  This succeeds.
With[{ser = Series[
    T /. First@Solve[eqn /. m -> n + Sqrt[J], T],
    {n, 0, 3}, 
    Assumptions -> n > 0]},
 Assuming[J > 0,
  Sqrt[J] + InverseSeries[ser, T]
  ]
 ]


$\sqrt{J}+J^{3/2} T^2+4 J^2 T^3+\frac{33}{2} J^{5/2} T^4+72 J^3
   T^5+O\left(T^6\right)$

Note that the final series in the first attempt is squared. It seems to take a different way of dealing with the 1/2 powers than rationalization, and either the constant term was forgotten or miscalculated.  Note that if we put it back in both places, we get the right answer:
Sqrt[J] + InverseSeries[
  ComposeSeries[
   SeriesData[m, Sqrt[J],
    {1/J^(3/4), -(2/J), 7/(4 J^(5/4)), -(1/J^(3/2)), 31/(32 J^(7/4)), -(1/J^2)},
    1, 7, 2],
   Sqrt[J] + SeriesData[T, 0, {1}, 2, 7, 1]]]^2


$\sqrt{J}+J^{3/2} T^2+4 J^2 T^3+\frac{33}{2} J^{5/2} T^4+72 J^3
   T^5+O\left(T^6\right)$


You used the OP's code, not the TeX formula. Not sure why there's a discrepancy. The OP used the TeX again in their answer. Maybe that's the one you should use? Of course, it differs only by a constant factor. Can't be all that important.

In the code below I use one of the five Root objects from Solve in AsymptoticSolve by first expressing the root  as a polynomial polyInM via theRootObjects[[1,1]][M] then solve polyInM for M[J] given T=0 in order to pass a center to AsymptoticSolve in which to expand around and then expand to order $5$:
myEqn = T == 
   1/(4 Pi M) (Sqrt[M^2 - (J/M)^2]/(M + Sqrt[M^2 - (J/M)^2]));
theRootObjects = M /. Solve[myEqn, M]
polyInM = theRootObjects[[1, 1]][M]

theM = M /. Solve[polyInM == 0 /. {T -> 0}, M] // Flatten

AsymptoticSolve[polyInM == 0, {M, theM[[1]]}, {T, 0, 5}]

$$
 -264 \pi ^4 J^{5/2} T^4-4 \pi ^2 J^{3/2} T^2+2304 \pi ^5 J^3 T^5+32 \pi ^3 J^2 T^3-\sqrt{J}
$$
I haven't confirmed the accuracy of the expansion.  Try expanding to a few hundred then back-substituting into the original expression and compare results.

I have solved the problem by myself. But without using the build-in Functions in Mathematica.(If any one can make the function like AsymptoticSolve to behave then just feel free to answer)
Set the expansion $M(T) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 T + \alpha_2 T^2 + \alpha_3 T^3 + o(T^3)$. And Let Mathematica to expand $$\frac{1}{4\pi M}\frac{\sqrt{M^2-(J/M)^2}}{M+\sqrt{M^2-(J/M)^2}}$$
w.r.t. $T$ to $\mathcal{O}(T^3)$. We can get 4 eqns by equalizing coefficients  the l.h.s. and r.h.s. of $$T = \frac{1}{4\pi M}\frac{\sqrt{M^2-(J/M)^2}}{M+\sqrt{M^2-(J/M)^2}}$$
And just use Solve to get the final answer.
The answer is
$$
M = \sqrt{J} + 4 J^{3/2} π^2 T^2 + 32 J^2 π^3 T^3 + \dots
$$
also see (2.4) in 2310.00848

So, what is the answer?

@yarchik Hi yarchik, I have just added the answer.
