# Numerical solution to a nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I am trying to solve the following ODE for $f(x)$:

$$x f' - f = \frac{(f')^2}{\gamma^2}[1-({f}')^\gamma]^2$$

where $\gamma < 0$ and real, which makes the ODE highly nonlinear. Since I am not looking for a linear solution ($f = x$ does solve the above ODE), I have reformulated the equation for $f(x) = x + F(x)$. Here is my input:

```
eq[gamma_] := 
 NDSolve[{(1 + F'[x])^2*(1 - (1 + F'[x])^gamma)^2/gamma^2 == 
    x*F'[x] - F[x], F[0.01] == 0.01}, F, {x, 0.01, 100}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

I had to use the suggested `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` in order to solve for the derivative. When I try to get a solution:

```
In[75]:= eq[-0.9]

During evaluation of In[75]:= NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.

Out[75]= {}
```

I got this error which, being honest, I don't quite fully understand. Could anyone help me?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The error message suggests that you give "initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions". As far as I can see, you have an initial condition on the value of the function. Would you be in a position to give one on the derivative as well, and retry?

Comment: I did the following: I gave an initial condition on $F'$ and obtained that for $F$ from the equation. Even so, I get error messages `NDSolve::ivcon: The given initial conditions were not consistent with the differential-algebraic equations. NDSolve will attempt to correct the values.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equation in the OP is a [Clairaut Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation).  They have the form
$$y = xy' + F(y') \tag{1}$$
Differentiating with respect to $x$ and factoring yields two equations
$$y''=0 \quad\text{and}\quad x = F'(y') \,.\tag{2}$$
The first yields a family of lines, called the *general solution* which in conjunction with (1) has the form
$$y=p\,x+F(p) \,.$$
The second yields the so-called *singular solution(s)*, which form the envelope of the general solution:
$$y = y_0 + \int_{x_0}^x (F')^{-1}(\xi) \; d\xi \,,$$
which depends on the invertibility of $F'$ and choice of branch for the inverse.
(One can see the elements of this exposition in @bbgodfrey's answer.)

We can use the analysis of (2) to solve the OP's equation.  The difficulty of numerically integrating the singular solution is discussed in an "aside" in my answer to [DSolve misses a solution of a differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86152/dsolve-misses-a-solution-of-a-differential-equation/89385#89385).  Let's first set up $F$:

```
ode = x f'[x] - f[x] == f'[x]^2/g^2 (1 - f'[x]^g)^2;

ClearAll[F, p];
F[p_] = f[x] - x f'[x] /. First@Solve[ode, f[x]] /. f'[x] -> p // Simplify
```

> ```
> (*  -((p^2 (-1 + p^g)^2)/g^2)  *)
> ```

#### The general solution

The formula is straightforward:

```
gensol[x_, p_] := p x + F[p];
```

#### The singular solution for `g = -9/10`

The tricky bit is inverting `F'[p]`.  I'll first present the solution, in the hopes that it will motivate interest in the explanation.

```
branchpts = K[1] /. Solve[
   Discriminant[20 - 81 K[1] #1^8 - 220 #1^9 + 200 #1^18 &[x], x] == 0,
   K[1], Reals]

(* inverse of F[p] *)
roots = {Piecewise[{
      {Root[20 - 81 t #1^8 - 220 #1^9 + 200 #1^18 &, 1], 
       branchpts[[1]] <= t <= branchpts[[2]]},
      {Root[20 - 81 t #1^8 - 220 #1^9 + 200 #1^18 &, 3], 
       branchpts[[2]] <= t}}],
    Piecewise[{
      {Root[20 - 81 t #1^8 - 220 #1^9 + 200 #1^18 &, 2], 
       branchpts[[1]] <= t <= branchpts[[2]]},
      {Root[20 - 81 t #1^8 - 220 #1^9 + 200 #1^18 &, 4], 
       branchpts[[2]] <= t}}]
    };

singsol = With[{t0 = branchpts[[1]]},
     NDSolveValue[
      {f'[t] == #^10, f[t0] == 0},
      f[x], {t, t0, 10},
      "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
        "WarningMessage" -> False}]
     ] & /@ roots;

Block[{g = -9/10, a = -1.5, b = 10},
 Show[
    Plot[Evaluate@
      Table[gensol[x, p], {p, Range[0 + 1/32, Sqrt[11], 1/32]^2}],
     {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray]],
    #,
    PlotRange -> {-1, 6},
    Options[#]
    ] &@ Plot[singsol + (-singsol[[2]] /. x -> 0) // Evaluate,
          {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[Medium]]
 ]
```

[image]

Since we set `g` equal to a rational number, inverting `F[p]` is equivalent to finding the roots of an associated polynomial.  As is (well?) known, `Root[.., k]` sorts the roots, and as the parameter `x` changes, there are discontinuities in `Root` objects. So it took some manual inspection to determine which `Root` objects constituted a given branch of the inverse of `F'[p]`.

If `g = -a/b`, with `a` and `b` positive integers, and `g >= 1/2`, then the polynomial referred to may be obtained as follows:

```
eqsing = Block[{g = -a/b},
   x + F'[q^b] // Simplify[a^2 #, a > 0 && b > 0 && q > 0] &
   ];
Collect[q^(2 a - b) eqsing, {q^b, q^a}]
```

> ```
> (*  2 a b - 2 b^2 + (-2 a b + 4 b^2) q^a - 2 b^2 q^(2 a) + a^2 q^(2 a - b) x  *)
> ```

We can check the roots at `x -> 0` with the solution above by plugging in and factoring (surprize! it factors):

```
Factor[q^(2 a - b) eqsing /. x -> 0]
```

> ```
> (*  -2 b (-1 + q^a) (a - b + b q^a)  *)
> ```

Now check the symbolic solutions with the slopes `p = q^b` of the branches of the singular solution.

```
Block[{a = 9, b = 10},
 {N@{Surd[(b - a)/b, a], 1}^b,
   D[singsol, x] /. x -> 0}]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {{0.0774264, 1.},
>    {0.0774265, 1.}}
> *)
> ```

Answer (score 8):

**Explanation of Error Noted in Question**

The computation in the question fails, because there is no real value of `F'[0.01]` for `F[0.01] == 0.01` and `gamma == -0.9`.  This can be seen by solving the ODE for `F[0.01]` as a function of `F'[0.01]`.

```
sf = f /. Flatten@Solve[((1 + F'[x])^2*(1 - (1 + F'[x])^gamma)^2/gamma^2 == 
     x*F'[x] - F[x]) /. gamma -> -0.9 /. F'[x] -> fp /. F[x] -> f /. x -> 0.01, f]
(* 0.01 fp - 1.23457 (1. + fp)^2 (1. - 1./(1. + fp)^0.9)^2 *)
FindMaximum[sf, fp]
(* {0.0000249876, {fp -> 0.00499627}} *)
```

So, choose `F[0.01]` less than that maximum, for instance,

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(1 + F'[x])^2*(1 - (1 + F'[x])^gamma)^2/
    gamma^2 == x*F'[x] - F[x], F[0.01] == 10^-5}, F, {x, 0.01, 100}, {gamma}, 
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]

Plot[s[-.9][x], {x, 0.01, 100}]
```

[image]

(It is convenient to use `ParametricNDSolveValue` for problems like this.)

**General Linear Solution**

Differentiating the ODE reveals that there are two categories of solutions.

```
der2 = Collect[Subtract @@ D[(1 + F'[x])^2*(1 - (1 + F'[x])^gamma)^2/gamma^2 == 
    x*F'[x] - F[x], x], F''[x], Simplify]
(* (-x + (2 (1 + F'[x])^(1 + gamma) (-1 + (1 + F'[x])^gamma))/gamma + 
   (2 (1 + F'[x]) (-1 + (1 + F'[x])^gamma)^2)/gamma^2) F''[x] *)
```

Solutions given by `F''[x] == 0` are, of course, linear, `F[x] == a x + b`.  Insert this into the ODE to obtain `b` as a function of `a`.

```
sb = -First[((1 + F'[x])^2*(1 - (1 + F'[x])^gamma)^2/gamma^2 == 
     x*F'[x] - F[x]) /. F[x] -> a x + b /. F'[x] -> a]
(* ((1 + a)^2 (1 - (1 + a)^gamma)^2)/gamma^2 *)

ParametricPlot[{sb /. gamma -> -0.9, a}, {a, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"F[0]", "F'[0]"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Black, Bold], 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

The linear solutions are a one-dimensional family, parameterized by `a` or `b`.  The solution obtained in the previous section is an example.

**Nonlinear Solutions**

The other factor of `der2` is an algebraic expression for `F'[x]`.

```
sx = First[der2]
(* -x + (2 (1 + F'[x])^(1 + gamma) (-1 + (1 + F'[x])^gamma))/gamma + 
   (2 (1 + F'[x]) (-1 + (1 + F'[x])^gamma)^2)/gamma^2 *)

ParametricPlot[{x + sx /. F'[x] -> fp /. gamma -> -0.9, fp}, {fp, -1, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, "F'[x]"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Black, Bold], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

For `x > -1` there are two solutions.  Visibly, `F'[0] == 0` for one of them, and the corresponding value of `F[0]` is given by

```
((1 + F'[x])^2*(1 - (1 + F'[x])^gamma)^2/gamma^2 == 
    x*F'[x] - F[x]) /. x -> 0 /. gamma -> -0.9 /. F'[0] -> 0
(* 0. == -F[0] *)
```

With these values, the solution is given by

```
fprime[gg_?NumericQ, xx_?NumericQ] := 
    fp /. FindRoot[sx /. {F'[x] -> fp, gamma -> gg, x -> xx}, {fp, xx/2}]
Flatten@NDSolve[{F'[x] == fprime[-.9, x], F[10^-4] == 10^-8/4}, F, {x, 10^-4, 100}];
Plot[F[x] /. %, {x, 10^-4, 100}, AxesLabel -> {x, F}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Black, Bold]]
```

[image]

`F[0]` is determined for the second solution by

```
((1 + F'[x])^2*(1 - (1 + F'[x])^gamma)^2/gamma^2 == 
    x*F'[x] - F[x]) /. x -> 0 /. gamma -> -0.9
(* 1.23457 (1 + F'[0])^2 (1 - 1/(1 + F'[0])^0.9)^2 == -F[0] *)
F'[x] /. FindRoot[0 == sx + x /. gamma -> -0.9, {F'[x], -.8, -.9}];
f01 = -First[%%] /. F'[0] -> %
(* -0.599484 *)

fprime1[gg_?NumericQ, xx_?NumericQ] := 
    fp /. FindRoot[sx /. {F'[x] -> fp, gamma -> gg, x -> xx}, {fp, -.8, -.9}]
Flatten@NDSolve[{F'[x] == fprime1[-.9, x], F[10^-4] == f01}, F, {x, 10^-4, 100}];
Plot[F[x] /. %, {x, 10^-4, 100}, AxesLabel -> {x, F}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Black, Bold]]
```

[image]

It is nearly linear, because `fprime1[-0.9, x]` is nearly constant.

Comment: @OliverFabioPiattella  The function in `FindRoot` is equivalent to `((x + sx) // Simplify) /. F'[x] -> fp`.  I can modify the answer to make this more transparent, if you like.  With respect to your question about the first nonlinear solution, `F`[x]` is equal to `x/2` at small `x`, as can be seen from the third figure.  So, `F[x]` is equal to `x^2/4` there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's all perfectly clear. I just needed to do some calculations (on the paper) to verify all.