# Complex first-order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, complex

I have a differential equation

$\frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{1+x^4}$

$x$ is a complex variable.

I want to solve it for some given initial condition, and plot the solution (real part vs. imaginary part).

I've tried this

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sqrt[1 + x[t]^4], x[0] == 1 + I}, x[t], {t, 0, 20}, Method -> "ExplicitMidpoint", "StartingStepSize" -> 1/1000];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[x[t]], Im[x[t]]} /.sol], {t, 0, 20}]
```

But the result is not what I was expecting, it should be something similar to this

[image]

But if I use the direction fields:

```
With[{xMin = 3}, StreamPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} &[Sqrt[1 + (x + I y)^4]], {x, -xMin, xMin}, {y, -xMin, xMin}]]
```

The result somehow resembles what I want:

[image]

How can I obtain the correct plot just by solving the differential equation?

Comment: `Plot3D[Re[Sqrt[1 + (re + im*I)^4]], {re, 0, 2}, {im, 0, 2}]` and `Plot3D[Im[Sqrt[1 + (re + im*I)^4]], {re, 0, 2}, {im, 0, 2}]` show a branch cut that is probably giving `NDSolve` fits. Sorry, I don't have a fix though!

Comment: What's the source of your expected plot?

Comment: @ Chris K Thanks for your comment. It's a part of my university homework.

Comment: Mathematica can solve this exactly by separating the variables and integrating, which will give same curve as Michael E2's, but I don't understand what parameter you are varying to get your other expected curves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This, which is substantially the same as the OP's, looks correct as far as it goes:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sqrt[1 + x[t]^4], x[0] == 1 + I}, 
   x, {t, -3, 3}, Method -> "ExplicitMidpoint", "StartingStepSize" -> 1/1000];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[x[t]], Im[x[t]]} /. sol], 
 Evaluate@Flatten@{t, x["Domain"] /. sol[[1]]}, AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

[image]

You can see from the `StreamPlot` that the stream lines reverse direction where the plot of `sol` stops.  That is why the integration stops.

A workaround is to raise the order by differentiating the rationalized ODE:

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[x'[t]^2 == 1 + x[t]^4, t], x[0] == 1 + I, 
    x'[0] == Sqrt[1 + x[0]^4]}, x, {t, -3, 3}, 
   Method -> "ExplicitMidpoint", "StartingStepSize" -> 1/1000];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[x[t]], Im[x[t]]} /. sol], 
 Evaluate@Flatten@{t, x["Domain"] /. sol[[1]]}, AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

[image]

Comment: This is very intelligent.

Comment: @Callmeatomato. Thanks for the compliment and the accept. I feel like it's a standard trick. The same trick was used on a much thornier problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160760/ndsolve-solves-this-ordinary-differential-equation-only-half-way) by Carl Woll and by me, as well as in one of the Q&A linked to it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Your answer to that question is frightening! I need a couple of months to digest that.