# Nonlinear first order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to solve:

$y - y' x - y'^2 = 0$.

One can guess a solution as $y = - x^2 / 4$.

However, with *Mathematica*, I have:

```
DSolve[y[x] - y'[x] x - (y'[x])^2 == 0, y[x], x]
```

which returns:

```
{{y[x] -> x C[1] + C[1]^2}}
```

that is also a correct solution.

How can I force *Mathematica* to return the former solution?

Comment: $y = -x^2/4$ the equilibrium manifold. A solution should have as many undetermined constants as the ODE degree.

Comment: Same problem here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86152/dsolve-misses-a-solution-of-a-differential-equation

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks! Your answer to that question is some sort of a journal article!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are called singular solutions. Mathematica sometimes do not find them.

A singular solution, when it exists, is tangent to the family of the general solutions (parameterized be the constant of integration you see there, which is $c_1$). Singular solutions can not be obtained from the general solution by substituting any value for the constant of integration.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For each specific value of $c_1$, we have one solution curve.

The tangent curve to all these solution curves (if it exists) is a singular solution. It exists at the max or min of the solution curves. Hence to find singular solution one way is to do the following (there can be more than one singular solution also)

```
 sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[y[x] - y'[x] x - y'[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  envelope = y[x] - sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now solve for `y[x]`, the singular solution

```
Solve[{envelope == 0, D[envelope, C[1]] == 0}, {y[x], C[1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Verify it satisfies the ode

```
sol = {{y -> Function[{x}, -(x^2/4)]}};
ode /. sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### second example

```
ode = 1 + y'[x]^2 == 1/y[x]^2;
sol = y[x] /. DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica does not find solution $y(x)=-1, y(x)=+1$. To find these

```
envelope = y[x] - sol[[1]];
Solve[{envelope == 0, D[envelope, C[1]] == 0}, {y[x], C[1]}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol = {{y -> Function[{x}, -1]}};
ode /. sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
envelope = y[x] - sol[[2]];
Solve[{envelope == 0, D[envelope, C[1]] == 0}, {y[x], C[1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Third example

```
ode = y'[x]^2 == 4 y[x];
sol = DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica does not give the solution $y=0$ which can't be obtained from the above for any values for $c_1$.

```
envelope = y[x] - (y[x] /. sol)[[1]]
Solve[{envelope == 0, D[envelope, C[1]] == 0}, {y[x], C[1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol2 = {{y -> Function[{x}, 0]}};
ode /. sol2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

References

(1) https://www.math24.net/singular-solutions-differential-equations/

(2) https://www.britannica.com/science/singular-solution

(3) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/rxO6yVz-_pk  See answer in this link by Devendra Kapadia which the above is mostly based on.

There are other ways to find these singular solutions. Reference (1) above shows more formal methods.

Comment: It should be noticed the command of Maple `dsolve(y(x) - diff(y(x), x)*x - diff(y(x), x)^2 = 0)` produces `y(x) = -x^2/4, y(x) = _C1^2 + _C1*x`.

Answer (score 6):

The equilibrium manifold as well as a generic solution can be obtained thru

```
n = 2;
y[x_] := Sum[Subscript[a, k] x^k, {k, 0, n}]
A = Table[Subscript[a, k], {k, 0, n}]
dif = y[x] - x y'[x] - y'[x]^2
coef = Take[CoefficientList[dif, x], {1, n + 1}]
sols = NSolve[coef == 0, A, Reals]
y[x] /. sols
```

Answer (score 6):

The new `DSolve` option `IncludeSingularSolutions` has been implemented in Mathematica 13.1. With this option, the singular solutions of all three examples can be easily found now.

First example:

```
DSolve[y[x] - y'[x] x - y'[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]
```

[image: result]

Second example:

```
ode = 1 + y'[x]^2 == 1/y[x]^2;
DSolve[ode, y[x], x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]
```

[image: result]

Third example:

```
ode = y'[x]^2 == 4 y[x];
DSolve[ode, y[x], x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]
```

[image: result]