# Why does NDSolve run into problems here?

Tags: differential-equations

I am looking at a particle moving in a funny potential, described by the following differential equation. The solution should be just some kind of periodic trajectory, why is there a problem here?

[image]

Edit: here is the code:

```
k = NDSolve[{x'[t]^2 + 1/Cos[x[t]]^2 == 2, x[0] == 0}, 
  x[t], {t, 0, 4}]
```

Comment: Please provide your Mathematica code for this interesting problem!

Comment: Assuming `x[t]` to be real your ode evaluates negative `x'[t]^2` for x[t]>= Pi/4 !!! That's why `NDSolve` stops for `x[t]==Pi/4`.

Comment: Both terms are squared, how can anything become negative?

Comment: @korni1990 It evaluates to false, because `1/Cos[x[t]]^2` will get larger than 2 and the other term is squared.

Comment: I see, thanks! But why is x[t] not simply decreasing after reaching the 'turning point' as it should? Is this not possible with NDSolve?

Comment: At the turning point, the ODE is equivalent to `x'[t] == 0`: The solution should be constant, not oscillatory. Check out `NDSolve[{x'[t]^2 + 1/Cos[x[t]]^2 == 2, x[0] == Pi/4}, x, {t, 0, 4}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]`.  The reason it's does not become constant in Domen's answer is that numerical error prevents the solution from reaching equilibrium. That's also why your code failed, although the different methods lead to different outputs.

Comment: @MichaelE2, is it correct to say, that the OP's DE has a singular solution $x=\pm \pi/4$, and that formally, the solution in my answer is "glued" together by two distinct nonsingular solutions? Technically, there can also be a larger constant portion of $x=\pm \pi/4$ at the turning points, and this will still be a valid solution.

Comment: @Domen Yes, that’s about right. Mathematically it’s similar to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89385. The resemblance can better be seen by analyzing Coolwater’s approach. Numerically I think it’s a bit different: The two solutions for `x’[t]` approach each other as `x[t]` approaches either singular solution `x[t] == ±Pi/4`. One solution leads towards the singular solution and the other leads away. The step size decreases as the solution gets close to `±Pi/4`, but eventually the implicit solver accidentally finds the branch leading away from the singular solution. I may answer in time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your differential equation has a singularity at $x(t) = \pi/2 \approx 1.54$, and that is why the integrator has troubles approaching that point. To solve this, use:

1. Initial value for the first derivative

$$x(0) = 0 \implies x'(0) = \pm 1$$

2. `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}`

```
k = NDSolve[{x'[t]^2 + 1/Cos[x[t]]^2 == 2, x'[0] == 1
   }, x[t], {t, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}] 
Plot[Evaluate[x[t]] /. k, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Cool thanks, that does the job indeed.

Comment: Your code in "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" gives an error: "NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at t == 7.7854479164218`; unable to continue." Are you using a different version, or did you do something not shown in the code?

Comment: @MichaelE2 No, I run exactly the same code in ``12.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)`` without errors.

Comment: In my case, `NDSolve` is probably stepping slightly below `-Pi/4`, but I wonder what changed (assuming it’s version-related, not OS/CPU related).

Answer (score 2):

Your initial condition implies `x[0] == 0 && x'[0] == 1`.
Using the corresponding 2nd order equation works well:

```
eq = D[x'[t]^2 + 1/Cos[x[t]]^2 == 2, t];
sols = x[t] /. NDSolve[{eq, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1}, x[t], {t, 0, 5}];
Plot[sols, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]