# Does Mathematica evaluate Sqrt[1] to +1 or -1 in this differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting through 14.0 or later**

---

This is known ode that `DSolve` generates a wrong extra solution.

Been there [since 2010](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/c/3WKcDTgtQkg/m/9-jSLAETSfUJ). I do not know if this was posted about here before or not. If it was, will delete this question. I did a search here and did not find one.

`DSolve` gives two solutions to this ode. But only one is correct.

I've been trying to guess how the wrong solution could have been generated and at what point.

```
ClearAll[y,x]
DSolve[{y'[x]==2*y[x]* (x *Sqrt[y[x]]-1),y[0]==1},y[x],x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first solution above should not be there. To find how `DSolve` came up with this, I solved this by hand to see where it could have gone wrong.

It seems this first solution could be generated if `DSolve` evaluated or replaced $\sqrt 1$ to $\pm 1$ near the end, when finding the constant of integration. But this would be very strange thing to do. As we always take the positive root (principal root) of square root of a positive number.

Here is my solution

Solve
\begin{gather*}
            \boxed{y^{\prime}-2 y \left(x \sqrt{y}-1\right)=0}
\end{gather*}
With initial conditions
$$
           y \left(0\right) = 1
$$

This is a Bernoulli ODE.

\begin{align*}
  y' = -2 y +2 x y^{\frac{3}{2}} \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Dividing both sides of ODE (1) by $y^{\frac{3}{2}}$ gives
\begin{align*}
     y'\frac{1}{y^{\frac{3}{2}}} &= -\frac{2}{\sqrt{y}} +2 x \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Let
\begin{align*}
     w &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \tag{5}
\end{align*}
Taking derivative of equation (5) w.r.t $x$ gives
\begin{align*}
     w'    &= -\frac{1}{2 y^{\frac{3}{2}}}y' \tag{6}
\end{align*}
Substituting equations (5) and (6) into equation (4) gives
\begin{align*}
-2 w^{\prime}\left(x \right)&= -2 w \left(x \right)+2 x\\ 
     w'  &= w -x \tag{7}
 \end{align*}
The above now is a linear ODE in $w \left(x \right)$. The integrating factor $\mu$ is
\begin{align*} 
 \mu &= {\mathrm e}^{-\int d x}\\
 &= {\mathrm e}^{-x}
\end{align*}
Eq (7) becomes
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}}}{ \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}\left( \mu w\right) &= \left(\mu \right) \left(-x\right) \\ 
\frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}}}{ \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}} \left(w \,{\mathrm e}^{-x}\right) &= -x {\mathrm e}^{-x}
\end{align*}
Integrating gives
\begin{align*}
         w \,{\mathrm e}^{-x} &= \int{- x {\mathrm e}^{-x} \,\mathrm{d} x}\\ 
         w \,{\mathrm e}^{-x} &= \left(x +1\right) {\mathrm e}^{-x} + c_1 
\end{align*}
Dividing both sides by the integrating factor $\mu={\mathrm e}^{-x}$ results in
\begin{align*}
          w &= x +1+c_{1} {\mathrm e}^{x}
\end{align*}

Replacing $w$ in the above by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$ using equation (5) gives the final solution.
$$
            \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} = x +1+c_{1} {\mathrm e}^{x}
$$
Initial conditions are now used to solve for $c_{1}$.

Substituting $x=0$ and $y=1$ in the above solution gives an equation to solve for the constant of integration. This is by taking $\sqrt{1}=1$. This gives
\begin{align*}
c_{1} = 0
\end{align*}
Substituting $c_{1}$ found above in the general solution found above gives
$$
                \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} = x +1
$$
Solving for $y \left(x \right)$ from the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y \left(x \right)}} = x +1$ gives the following solution
\begin{align*}
y \left(x \right) &= \frac{1}{\left(x +1\right)^{2}}
\end{align*}

Now, if `DSolve` also used $\sqrt{1}=-1$, then $c_1=-2$ and this would result in that extra first solution `DSolve` gave.

Question is: Do you think this is what happened? Or do you see another path that could have caused `DSolve` to generate the first solution?

V 13.0 on windows 10

Comment: Same problem as `Dsolve`ing $y' = 2 \sqrt{y}$ -- omits the trivial solution, gives half-wrong solutions (note that the derivative is always nonnegative, but $y = (x-C)^2$ is decreasing half the time).  The WA version (further wrong by omitting the arbitrarily horizontally translated solutions) is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4343762/spurious-solution-to-differential-equation/4346109#4346109).

Comment: Related to @EricTowers' example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86152/dsolve-misses-a-solution-of-a-differential-equation/89385#89385

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The procedure of `DSolve`

Where the OP solves for `C[1]` in the by-hand solution ($ {1}/{\sqrt{y}} = x +1+c_{1} e^{x}$), `DSolve` first solves for $y$ -- its process is get the general solution if possible; then specialize to the BCs.  Solving for $y$ squares both sides of the equation, introducing an extraneous solution. You could say `DSolve` flunks 8th grade algebra. :)

@user64494's 1st & 4th steps are basically what happens (+1).  Here are the steps I refer to, which I repeat to define some variables used later, although I think `DSolve` calls `Solve` instead of `Reduce`:

```
ode = y'[x] == 2*y[x]*(x*Sqrt[y[x]] - 1);
gensol = DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
(*  {{y[x] -> 1/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^2}}  *)

const = Solve[y[0] == 1 /. DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction[gensol]]
(*  {{C[1] -> -2}, {C[1] -> 0}}  *)

ivpsol = Flatten[gensol /. const, 1]
(*  {{y[x] -> 1/(1 - 2 E^x + x)^2}, {y[x] -> 1/(1 + x)^2}}  *)
```

### Checking solutions

Checking functional solutions can be hard when we're dealing with branch cuts in equations.  Here's one way it could be done in this case (and could often be expensive in other cases).  At least this works in V13; I don't remember `Simplify` returning an inequality given an equation to simplify before, but maybe I never tried.  We get the domains of each solution.  Each domain should be an interval containing the boundary condition.  The code below checks for an interval but it does not check that `0` belongs to it.  (You'd have to parse the locations of the BCs, and the code is going to get longer. In this case `DSolve` returns solutions all of whose domains contain `0`. Perhaps this always happens and there's no need to check it.)

```
ivpdomains = Simplify[
  ode /. DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction[ivpsol],
  x \[Element] Reals]
truesol = Pick[ivpsol,
  RegionDimension@ImplicitRegion[#, {x}] & /@ ivpdomains,
  1]
(*
  {x == 0, x/(1 + x) == 0 || x >= -1}
  {{y[x] -> 1/(1 + x)^2}}
*)
```

### Alternate approach

You can also use my trick from
[Accessing Reduce from DSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10699/accessing-reduce-from-dsolve/63676#63676)
to use `Reduce` in `Solve`, which is more fastidious about 8th grade algebra:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Solve}, Unprotect[Solve];
 Solve[eq_, v_, opts___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := 
  Block[{$in = True, $res1, $res2}, 
   Solve[eq, v, Method -> Reduce, opts]];
 Protect[Solve];
 DSolve[{ode, y[0] == 1}, y[x], x] // 
  Simplify[#, x \[Element] Reals] &
 ]
```

> Solve::useq: The answer found by `Solve` contains equational condition(s)...
>
> ```
> {{y[x] -> ConditionalExpression[1/(1 + x)^2, x >= -1]}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes `DSolve` has problems with `Sqrt`.

If you substitute `Sqrt[y[x]]->z[x]` the new ode

```
ode = Simplify[Derivative[1][y][x] == 2 (-1 + x Sqrt[y[x]]) y[x] /.y -> Function[x, z[x]^2] , z[x] > 0] 
(*x z[x]^2 == z[x] + Derivative[1][z][x]*)
```

is easily and correctly solved:

```
DSolve[{ode,z[0]==1}, z,x]
(*{{z -> Function[{x}, 1/(1 + x)]}}*)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

Here is my explanation. Mathematica 13.0.0 correctly solves

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == 2*y[x]*(x*Sqrt[y[x]] - 1)}, y, x]
```

> `{{y -> Function[{x}, 1/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^2]}}`

, but does not take into account that this is a true solution
under the condition `1 + x + E^x C[1]>=0` only:

```
y'[x] - 2*y[x]*(x*Sqrt[y[x]] - 1) /. 
{{y -> Function[{x}, 1/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^2]}}
```

> `{-((2 (1 + E^x C[1]))/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^3) - ( 2 (-1 + x Sqrt[1/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^2]))/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^2}`

, and then

```
FullSimplify[{-((2 (1 + E^x C[1]))/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^3) -
( 2 (-1 + x Sqrt[1/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^2]))/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^2}, 
 Assumptions ->1 +x + E^x C[1] >= 0]
```

> `{0}`

```
FullSimplify[{-((2 (1 + E^x C[1]))/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^3) - (2 (-1 + 
x Sqrt[1/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^2]))/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^2}, 
Assumptions ->1 +x + E^x C[1] < 0]
```

> `{-((2 x (-1 + Sign[1 + x + E^x C[1]]^3))/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^3)}`

As I understand it, she does

```
Reduce[1 == 1/(1 + x + E^x C[1])^2 /. x -> 0, C[1]]
```

> `C[1] == -2 || C[1] == 0`

, not selecting only `C[1]==0` (`1+0+(-2)==-1` so `C[1]==-2` does not produce a solution).

The solution of the problem is unique because of

```
D[2*y*(x*Sqrt[y] - 1), y] /. {x -> 0, y -> 1}
```

> `-2`

We see a bug, however, Mathematica does not think `Sqrt[1]==-1`.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like under 12.3,  DSolve, when given initial conditions,  is returning two solutions  because Mathematica is treating $\sqrt{y}$ in the DE as multi-valued.  This to me is the more general solution. The solution $y_1(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ satisfies the IVP:
$$y'=2y(x\sqrt{y}-1); y(0)=1
$$
and the solution $y_2(x)=\frac{1}{(-1+2e^x-x)^2}$ satisfies:
$$
y'=2y(-x\sqrt{y}-1); y(0)=1
$$
when $\sqrt{y}$ is interpreted as principal-valued.

Consider the IVP:
$$
y'=2y(xy^{1/3}-1),y(0)=1
$$
In this case DSolve returns  three solutions apparently corresponding to the three values of $y^{1/3}=|y|^{1/3}e^{\frac{i}{3}(\theta+2n\pi)}$.  I have not checked it but I suspect in this case, the three solutions satisfy the DE:

$$
y'=2y(x|y|^{1/3}e^{\frac{i}{3}(\theta+2 n\pi)}-1),y(0)=1, n=0,1,2
$$

Comment: Living in the real domain, `DSolve[{y'[x] == 2*y[x]*(x*Surd[y[x], 3] - 1), y[0] == 1}, y[x], x]` returns `Solve[(1/(8 y[x]))
  3 E^(-2 x/
    3) (6 UnitStep[y[x]] ((-y[x])^(2/3) - y[x]^(2/3)) - 
     6 (-y[x])^(2/3) + (9 + 6 x) y[x]) == 9/8, y[x]]`. BTW,  do your three solutions  not contradict [Cauchy-Kowalevski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_problem)?

Comment: Just to compare, the Maple command `dsolve({diff(y(x), x) = 2*y(x)*(x*sqrt(y(x)) - 1), y(0) = 1}, y(x))` results in `y(x) = 1/(x + 1)^2` and the Maple command `dsolve({diff(y(x), x) = 2*y(x)*(x*y(x)^(1/3) - 1), y(0) = 1})` produces `y(x) = -8/(exp((2*x)/3) - 2*x - 3)^3`.