# Is there any way we can draw its slope field without solving the differential equation?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Some equations are difficult to solve, so perhaps we can plot a function of the equation to see roughly how the solution looks. The same is true for differential equations, where we can observe the integral curve by drawing its slope field.

I have a differential equation:
$$ y^2=4+4\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 $$
Then I can get $y'=±\sqrt{\frac{y^2-4}{4}}$. So I want to plot the $+$ part:

```
StreamPlot[{1, Sqrt[((y^2 - 4)/4) ]}, {x, -1, 5}, {y, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

But actually I know the solution of this differential equations [from here](https://youtu.be/ifbaAqfqpc4?t=141) is:

```
sol[x_]:=1/2 (c E^(x/2)+(4 E^(-x/2))/c)
```

And then something strange happened:

```
c = 1;
sol[x_] := 1/2 (c E^(x/2) + (4 E^(-(x/2)))/c);
Show[StreamPlot[{1, Sqrt[1/4 (y^2 - 4)]}, {x, -1, 5}, {y, 0, 5}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[sol[x]], {x, -1, 6}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue]]
```

[image]

It looks like this slope field is only correct within a certain range (e.g. the right-hand side). But exactly where the turning point is, we may need `sol` to determine that. **But the purpose of my drawing the slope field is to know the information of `sol`, how can I in turn draw the slope field by the information of `sol`? This is confusing me. So I ask here.**

Is there any way I can draw the direction field correctly without any information from `sol`?

Comment: Your `sol[x_]` is not a solution to the + part, no? It's a solution to the orginal DE, though, yes?  (The direction field is two-valued, *as you point out*, but you draw only one of the values....It's unclear to me why it's confusing.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 In fact, I wanted to draw all the parts where the `sol[x]` was (including the + and - parts) but I found I needed the `sol[x]` itself to know which part of the slope field was correct and which part was wrong. This seems to defeat my original purpose of drawing the slope field. So I feel  confused

Comment: For each $x_0$, at the initial condition $(x_0, y_0=2)$, there are three solutions, including the singular solution $y(x)=2$. A similar thing is happening in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89385/4999), Fig. 3, bottom left, where I show the two-sheeted cover of the slope field (if you will allow the integral curves to represent the slopes as in `StreamPlot`).  A solution to the + part has the form $$y(x)=
\begin{cases}
  \left(e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(x-x_0\right)}+e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(x-x_0\right)}\right) & x>x_0 \\
 2 & x\le x_0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Probably not easy to get out of `DSolve`, though, unless it has improved its handling of singular solutions. (See previously linked answer.)

Answer (score 4):

> But actually I know the solution of this differential equations is:

There are more than one solution.

You picked the wrong solution to try. Using the other one gives what you were expecting to show:

```
c = 1;
sol[x_] := 1/2*(Exp[-1/2*x]^2*c^2 + 4)/Exp[-1/2*x]/c;
Show[StreamPlot[{1, Sqrt[1/4 (y^2 - 4)]}, {x, -1, 5}, {y, 0, 5}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[sol[x]], {x, -1, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To see the other region this works (note need to use `c=-1` for it to show up). Now $y$ is limited to `{y, 0, -5}`

```
c = -1;
sol[x_] := 1/2*(Exp[-1/2*x]^2*c^2 + 4)/Exp[-1/2*x]/c;
Show[StreamPlot[{1, -Sqrt[1/4 (y^2 - 4)]}, {x, -1, 5}, {y, 0, -5}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[sol[x]], {x, -1, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Other solutions are $y=2$ and $y=-2$. From existence and uniqueness theory for first order ode, the general solution exist for $y>2$ or $y<-2$. The other two solutions are singular solutions.

Comment: How do you get that "the other one" you said?? My `sol` is the solution of the differential equations indeed. Is the slope field it is in cannot plot with MMA?

Comment: Could you give me a response please?

Comment: @yode oh I did not notice you had question. I simply solved this using Maple. It showed 2 general solutions. I tried one, did not work/match the slope curve plot, and then tried the second, which matched. So I used the second one.  I can post the code and the output if you want.

Comment: My `sol` is the solution of the differential equations indeed. Is the slope field it is in cannot plot correctly with MMA?

Comment: @yode, there might be some issue here. I see you had discussion with Michael about this also. I used the slopefiled you had, and just matched it with the solution by Maple. I am sorry, but the above is all what I can provide on this now as I have to spend time on other things. Hope you can find solution that satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Get an overview of the solutions in the reals with Reduce.

```
eq = y[x]^2 == 4 + 4 y'[x]^2;

red = Reduce[eq, y'[x], Reals]

(*   (y[x] <= -2 && 
    (Derivative[1][y][x] == -(1/2) Sqrt[-4 + y[x]^2] || 
     Derivative[1][y][x] == 1/2 Sqrt[-4 + y[x]^2])) 
     || 
     (y[x] >= 2 && 
    (Derivative[1][y][x] == -(1/2) Sqrt[-4 + y[x]^2] || 
     Derivative[1][y][x] == 1/2 Sqrt[-4 + y[x]^2]))          *)
```

Which gives all the solutions @Nasser showed perfectly, even the two singular one

```
{red /. y[x] -> -2, red /. y[x] -> 2} // Union

(*   {Derivative[1][y][x] == 0 || Derivative[1][y][x] == 0}   *)
```

Get the two general solutions via DSolve

```
ysol[aa_, bb_] = y /. DSolve[{eq, y[aa] == bb}, y, x]

Through[ysol[aa, bb][x]] // 
 Union[#, SameTest -> (Simplify[#1 - #2, 
        Assumptions -> Element[{aa, bb}, Reals]] === 0 &)] &

(*   {-((E^(-x/2) (-2 E^aa + bb^2 E^aa + 2 E^x - 
     bb E^(aa/2) Sqrt[(-4 + bb^2) E^aa]))/(-bb E^(aa/2) + 
   Sqrt[(-4 + bb^2) E^aa])), 
     (E^(-x/2) (-2 E^aa + bb^2 E^aa + 2 E^x + 
    bb E^(aa/2) Sqrt[(-4 + bb^2) E^aa]))/(
    bb E^(aa/2) + Sqrt[(-4 + bb^2) E^aa])}   *)
```