# Question on DSolve's IncludeSingularSolutions option. Why some output do not agree with definition?

Tags: differential-equations

in V 13.1, `DSolve` added a very useful option [IncludeSingularSolutions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IncludeSingularSolutions.html) which according to Mathematica own documentation says

> Singular solutions cannot be obtained by assigning finite numerical
> values to the arbitrary constants in the general solution for a
> nonlinear differential equation.

But I see 100's of solutions given that `DSolve` says they are singular, but can be obtained from the general solution. Here are just 3 examples

```
DSolve[x^2*(y'[x])^2 - y[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x]
DSolve[x^2*(y'[x])^2 - y[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x,  IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first one is the general solution. But we see that by setting `c1` to zero, it gives `0` as the solution. But Mathematica says that `y[x] -> 0` is a singular solution.

Here are two more examples.

```
DSolve[x*(y'[x])^2 - (2*x + 3*y[x])*y'[x] + 6*y[x] == 0, y[x], x]
DSolve[x*(y'[x])^2 - (2*x + 3*y[x])*y'[x] + 6*y[x] == 0, y[x], x,  IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DSolve[x^2*(y'[x])^2 - 5*x*y[x]*y'[x] + 6*y[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x]
DSolve[x^2*(y'[x])^2 - 5*x*y[x]*y'[x] + 6*y[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now here is an example, where the singular solution generated is a true one

```
  DSolve[y[x]==y'[x]*x+1/y'[x],y[x],x,IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ignoring the `Indeterminate` one, (that should not show up), we see that `{y[x] -> -2 Sqrt[x]}, {y[x] -> 2 Sqrt[x]}` are true singular solutions, because no value for the constant of integration will generate these solutions.

I see no **possible issues** tag in the help page on this command.

my question is: Why `DSolve` says these are singular solutions when they can be obtained from the general solution?

I was using Mathematica to verify my hand solution when I noticed this.

V 13.2 on windows 10.

Comment: I think the documentation is giving a simplified description of singular solutions without getting into having to defined singularities of the contact field.  What you're observing is the coincidence of a singular solution with an ordinary solution (somewhat like multiple roots in algebraic equations).

Comment: One of the steps it does is set all derivatives of `y` to zero in the ODE and see if there are constant solutions to the resulting algebraic equation.  These do not seem to be checked against special values of the general solution. (This is how the `y[x] -> 0` solutions are added to the solution set.) See ``PrintDefinitions@DSolve`DSolveSingularSolutions`` for code.

Comment: It also takes the limits of the general solution as `C[1]` approaches 0, ±∞. These are usually not, strictly speaking, "singular solutions" (at least not of the form found in your Clairaut equation).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: @Nasser this time we did not manage to do it in 10 different ways :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I approach singular solutions.  I sometimes have to think about a step somewhere in the middle, so it's not quite an algorithm yet. I think of an ODE $F(x,y(x),y'(x))=0$ as a manifold $F(x,y,p)=0$ in 3-space on which there is a vector field, called the *contact field*, corresponding to $p=dy/dx$: The "slope" of a solution curve as viewed from above is given by the height $p$ of the surface.  (The solution or integral curve is the parametric curve $(x,y,p)=(x,y(x),y'(x))$.)

There are two sorts of singularities: Those in the manifold itself (such as self-intersections), and those where the field is undefined, which happens when $\partial F/\partial p = 0$.

`DSolve` also adds solutions, under `IncludeSingularSolutions`, that are limits of the general solution at boundaries of the domain of the integration parameter (usually `C[1]`). In fact it seems to check only infinity and zero and does not look into whether there are other boundaries in the domain of `C[1]`.

Since we're looking at examples of `DSolve`, we can construct mesh functions that show the solution curves on the ODE manifold, which I wanted to share.

#### Example 1

```
ode = x^2*(y'[x])^2 - y[x]^2 == 0;
manifold = ode /. {y'[x] -> p, y[x] -> y};
Reduce[{manifold, D[manifold, p]}, {x, y, p}] (* sing sols *)
dsol = DSolve[ode, y, x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]
(*ode/.dsol//Simplify*) (* check dsol *)
{mfns, mesh} = dsol // solToMeshFunction // Transpose
ContourPlot3D[manifold // Evaluate,
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1.01}, {p, -5.01, 5},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 MeshFunctions -> mfns // Evaluate,
 Mesh -> mesh /. Automatic -> 15 // Evaluate,
 MeshShading -> RandomColor[RGBColor[_, _, _, 0.5], {4, 4, 2}]]
```

> ```
> (*
>  * A sing. pt. (not sol.) and sing. sol. y == 0
> (x == 0 && y == 0) || (y == 0 && p == 0)
>
> {{y -> Function[{x}, C[1]/x]},
>  {y -> Function[{x}, x C[1]]},
>  {y -> Function[{x}, 0]}}
>
> {{Function[{x, y, p}, -p x^2], Function[{x, y, p}, p], 
>   Function[{x, y, p}, p - 0]}, (* redundent b/c sol is redundant *)
>  {Automatic, Automatic, {0}}}
> *)
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> *The tartan grid is formed by the two families of solutions,
> the hyperbolas and lines.  The line `y == 0` is a singular locus
> of the manifold that happens to be a solution to the ODE,
> as well as a particular value of the general solution.*

#### Example 2

```
ode = x*(y'[x])^2 - (2*x + 3*y[x])*y'[x] + 6*y[x] == 0;
manifold = ode /. {y'[x] -> p, y[x] -> y};
Reduce[{manifold, D[manifold, p]}, {x, y, p}] (* sing sols *)
dsol = DSolve[ode, y, x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]
(*ode/.dsol//Simplify*)
{mfns, mesh} = dsol // solToMeshFunction // Transpose
ContourPlot3D[manifold // Evaluate,
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1.01}, {p, -3.01, 7},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 MeshFunctions -> mfns // Evaluate,
 Mesh -> mesh /. Automatic -> 15 // Evaluate,
 MeshShading -> RandomColor[RGBColor[_, _, _, 0.5], {4, 4, 2}],
 ViewPoint -> {20, 0, 0}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}]
```

> ```
> (*
>  * A sing. pt. (not a sol.) and sing. locus (not a sol.)
> (x == 0 && y == 0) ||
>  (y == (2 x)/3 && p == 2) || (* y == 2x/3 is split into two cases *)
>  (y == (2 x)/3 && x != 0 && p == 2)
>
> {{y -> Function[{x}, x^3 C[1]]},
>  {y -> Function[{x}, 2 x + C[1]]},
>  {y -> Function[{x}, 0]}}  (* spurious *)
>
> {{Function[{x, y, p}, p/(3 x^2)], Function[{x, y, p}, -2 x + y], 
>   Function[{x, y, p}, p - 0]}, {Automatic, Automatic, {0}}}
> *)
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> *The line `y == 0` is not a singular locus
> of the manifold, just the point at the origin.
> It happens to be a solution to the ODE,
> in fact a particular value of the general solution,
> and perhaps that's why it was retained in the output of `DSolve[]`.
> As can be seen, `y == 2x/3`, which shows up in `Reduce[]`
> output, is a self-intersection of the manifold. It is at
> a height of `p == 2` and would have to have slope `2`
> to be a solution.  So it's not a singular solution.*

#### Example 3

This is a classic Clairaut equation.

```
ode = y[x] == y'[x]*x + 1/y'[x];
manifold = ode /. {y'[x] -> p, y[x] -> y};
Reduce[{manifold, D[manifold, p]}, {x, y, p}] (* sing sols *)
dsol = Cases[DSolve[ode, y, x, IncludeSingularSolutions -> True], 
  s_ /; FreeQ[s, Indeterminate]]
(*ode/.dsol//Simplify*)
{mfns, mesh} = dsol // solToMeshFunction // Transpose
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[p y == 1 + p^2 x, {x, -5, 5.01},
  {y, -5, 5.007}, {p, -10.01, 10},
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
  PlotPoints -> {15, 45, 45},
  MeshFunctions -> mfns // Evaluate,
  Mesh -> mesh /. Automatic -> 
     Subdivide[-(9.5^(1/3)), (9.5^(1/3)), 25]^3 // 
   Evaluate,
  MeshShading -> RandomColor[RGBColor[_, _, _, 0.5], {4, 2, 2}]]]
```

> ```
> (*
>  * Two singular solutions (or one if y^2 == 4x)
> (y == -2 Sqrt[x] || y == 2 Sqrt[x]) && x != 0 && p == y/(2 x)
>
> {{y -> Function[{x}, 1/C[1] + x C[1]]},
>  {y -> Function[{x}, -2 Sqrt[x]]},
>  {y -> Function[{x}, 2 Sqrt[x]]}}
>
> {{Function[{x, y, p}, p], 
>   Function[{x, y, p}, p - -(1/Sqrt[Max[1.*10^-16, x]])], 
>   Function[{x, y, p}, 
>    p - 1/Sqrt[Max[1.*10^-16, x]]]}, {Automatic, {0}, {0}}}
> *)
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> *The top view shows that the tangent planes are vertical along the singular solutions.  This is equivalent to $\partial F/\partial p = 0$.  See [DSolve misses a solution of a differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86152/dsolve-misses-a-solution-of-a-differential-equation/89385#89385) for a more
> in-depth analysis of a similar singular solution.*

#### `solToMeshFunctions`

```
solToMeshFunction // ClearAll;
solToMeshFunction::dim = "Dimension of solution ``, expected 1.";
solToMeshFunction::fo = "First-order ODEs only (no systems).";
solToMeshFunction[sols_ : {__List}] := 
  Flatten[solToMeshFunction /@ sols, 1];
solToMeshFunction[{sol_Rule}] := solToMeshFunction[sol];
solToMeshFunction[{_Rule, __Rule}] := Null /; (
    Message[solToMeshFunction::fo]; False);
solToMeshFunction[sol : (y_[x_] -> _)] := 
  solToMeshFunction[DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction[sol]];
solToMeshFunction[sol : (y_ -> Verbatim[Function][{x_}, s_])] /; 
   FreeQ[sol, _C] :=
  With[{yp = y'[x] /. sol /. 
      Power[b_, r_] /; EvenQ[Denominator@r] :> 
       Power[Max[10.^-16, b], r]},
   {{Function @@ Hold[{x, y, p}, p - yp], {0}}}
   ];
solToMeshFunction[sol : (y_ -> Verbatim[Function][{x_}, s_])] :=
  With[{param = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[s, _C, Infinity]},
   If[Length@param != 1,
    Message[solToMeshFunction::dim, Length@param]
    ];
   With[{mf = First@param /. Replace[
          Solve[p == (y'[x] /. sol), param],
          {} :> Solve[y == s, param]
          ] /. 
        Power[b_, r_] /; EvenQ[Denominator@r] :> 
         Power[Max[10.^-16, b], r]},
     {Function @@ Hold[{x, y, p}, #], Automatic} & /@ mf
     ] /; Length@param == 1
   ];
```

Comment: Wonderful stuff as per usual!!!

Answer (score 3):

I will give it a go with the risk of humiliating myself.

From the [**`documentation`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IncludeSingularSolutions.html) there's a worked example; see Properties & Relations. That example explains how to obtain the singular solution(s) from the envelope for the family of curves by the general solution.

In that example we are told that we need to consider the general solution of a nonlinear ODE and to construct the envelope for the family of curves defined by the general solution. After that, we wish to consider the solution and its derivative by setting the latter to zero and eliminate the constant. Solve for `y[x]` and that gives the output of [**`IncludeSingularSolutions`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IncludeSingularSolutions.html). The worked example in the docs is the following:

Step 1:

```
DSolve[y[x] == x*y'[x] + y'[x]^2 - 3 y'[x], y[x], x]
```

which gives

> [image: docs1]

Then, with

```
sol = y[x] == (y[x] /. %[[1]])
```

> [image: docs2]

we [**`Eliminate`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html?v=13.2)

```
Eliminate[{sol, D[sol[[2]], C[1]] == 0}, C[1]]
```

> [image: docsel]

and we solve

```
Solve[%, y[x]]
```

> [image: docs3]

We are now at a position to compare to `IncludeSingularSolutions -> True`

```
DSolve[y[x] == x*y'[x] + y'[x]^2 - 3 y'[x], y[x], x, 
 IncludeSingularSolutions -> True]
```

> [image: docs]

As far as I can tell, but maybe I am missing something(?), we can follow the same steps as the example for case mentioned.

```
DSolve[y[x] == y'[x]*x + 1/y'[x], y[x], x]
sol = y[x] == (y[x] /. %[[1]])
```

> [image: ds1]

and then

```
Eliminate[{sol, D[sol[[2]], C[1]] == 0}, C[1]]
Solve[%, y[x]]
```

> [image: f]

**Edit 1: including the other examples mentioned in the OP**

The first example

```
de = DSolve[x^2*(y'[x])^2 - y[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x]
sol1 = y[x] == (y[x] /. de[[1]])
sol2 = y[x] == (y[x] /. de[[2]])
```

> [image: edit1]

and then

```
Eliminate[{sol1, D[sol1[[2]], C[1]] == 0}, C[1]]
Eliminate[{sol2, D[sol2[[2]], C[1]] == 0}, C[1]]
```

> [image: edit12]

and we got the `y[x]->0` solution.

**Edit 2: the second example from the OP**

```
de = DSolve[x*(y'[x])^2 - (2*x + 3*y[x])*y'[x] + 6*y[x] == 0, y[x], 
  x]
sol1 = y[x] == (y[x] /. de[[1]])
sol2 = y[x] == (y[x] /. de[[2]])
```

> [image: edit21]

```
Eliminate[{sol1, D[sol1[[2]], C[1]] == 0}, C[1]]
Eliminate[{sol2, D[sol2[[2]], C[1]] == 0}, C[1]]
```

> [image: edit22]

**Edit 3: the third example**

```
de = DSolve[x^2*(y'[x])^2 - 5*x*y[x]*y'[x] + 6*y[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x]
sol1 = y[x] == (y[x] /. de[[1]])
sol2 = y[x] == (y[x] /. de[[2]])
```

> [image: edit31]

```
Eliminate[{sol1, D[sol1[[2]], C[1]] == 0}, C[1]]
Eliminate[{sol2, D[sol2[[2]], C[1]] == 0}, C[1]]
```

> [image: edit32]

Comment: Nice explanation. What does this show for the first two examples in the OP, the two with the spurious-looking singular solution `y[x] -> 0` that the OP raises concerns about?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh sorry. I had those cases as well with this method, then deleted the post to update, then undeleted and I messed up. Let me update with the `y[x]->0`. They can be derived in a similar manner. So, all in all it says that I am stupid :-)

Comment: @MichaelE2 please have a look at the edit. If you think I should do the other cases for completeness let me know.

Comment: Great. That may indeed be how `y[x] -> 0` shows up in the output of `DSolve`. I'd like to point out, however, that `Solve[x == 0 && y[x] == 0, y[x]]` returns no solution. And mathematically, the solution to it should be a function defined at only a single point (which is hard to see as valid solution to a differential equation).  Seems to support the OP's point that `y[x] -> 0` is spurious. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for your kind words and upvote :) About the comment you made pertaining to `Solve[x == 0 && y[x] == 0, y[x]]` while I appreciate the argument you're raising, from the documentation my understanding was that `Solve` is used to get an expression for `y[x]` as the output of `Eliminate` might be something like `4y[x]` or `y[x]^2` as in the first two examples, and so in the case that `Eliminate` gives back `y[x]` this is used by ` IncludeSingularSolutions -> True`, but maybe that's too naive.

Comment: `Solve[x == 0 && y[x] == 0, y[x]]` returns `{}`, i.e. no solution. So `DSolve` should get no solution this way, right? Or do I misunderstand? (I think `DSolve` gets `y[x] -> 0` from the other process it applies, taking the limit as `C[1] -> 0`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, this is what I tried to phrase but perhaps I was not clear. That the `y[x]->0` pops out from the process described in the documentation and also in my answer. I thought you meant to write it as a comment that in the `y[x]->0` I should have added another `Solve` command after the `Eliminate` and just pointed that it was not necessary, that's all :-)