# How to Solve $y'(x)=x\ln(y(x))$ with $y(1)=1$ using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

The solution to $y'=x \ln(y)$ with initial conditions $y(1)=1$ is $y=1$.

How to persuade `DSolve` to obtain this solution?

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = y'[x] == x Log[y[x]];
ic = y[1] == 1;
sol = DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can see that $y=1$ is solution that also satisfies the ic by looking at direction field.

```
ClearAll[x, y];
fTerm = x Log[y];
StreamPlot[ {1, fTerm}, {x, -1, 3}, {y, 0, 2},
 Axes -> True,
 Frame -> False,
 PlotTheme -> "Classic",
 AspectRatio -> 1 / GoldenRatio,
 StreamPoints -> {{{{1, 1}, Red}, Automatic}},
 Epilog -> {{Red, PointSize[.025], Point[{1, 1}]}},
 PlotLabel -> Style[Text[Row
    [{"Solution curve with initial conditions at {", 1, ",", 1,"}"}]], 14]
 ]
```

[image]

V 12.0 on windows 10

Comment: The function y[x]=1 is a singular solution of the ODE under consideration which cannot be obtained from  its general solution   y[x]->(LogIntegral^(-1))[x^2/2+Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]] produced by DSolve[y'[x] == x Log[y[x]], y[x], x]. Every soft has its limitations.

Comment: It's the limit of the general solution as `C[1] -> -Infinity`, but *M* does not seem to be very robust with respect to the inverse function of `LogIntegral[]`. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57910/dsolve-not-finding-solution-i-expected

Comment: @Michael E2: it's unclear whether  the limit of the general solution as C[1] -> -Infinity is a solution of the ODE under consideration. This should be based. I don't think the proff is simple. In any case that limit is not a particular solution.

Comment: @user64494 Pointwise convergence seems pretty clear to me. Just think about it.

Comment: @Michael E2: I prefer arguments and references over ungrounded words.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, so do I, but I would not want to deprive you of the pleasure of figuring it out.

Comment: @Michael E2: In any case Limit[(LogIntegral^(-1))[x^2/2+Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]],Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]->-Infinity] fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98198/discussion-between-michael-e2-and-user64494).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AsymptoticDSolveValue` (introduced in V11.3) seems to be more robust than `DSolve` here and confirms (or at least not falsifies) the solution you want (as @MichaelE2 points out we cannot really get a rigorous solution from a finite series expansion this way):

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[
  {y'[x] == x Log[y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
  y[x], {x, 0, (*arbitrarily high finite order*) 10}
]
```

> 1

or to see how this works we can get the series expression in `x` before taking the limit $x\to 0$

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[
  {y'[x] == x Log[y[x]], y[0] == y0}, 
  y[x], {x, 0, 2}
]
Limit[Evaluate[%], y0 -> 1]
```

> y0 + 1/2 x^2 Log[y0]
>
> 1

Comment: I think there's a problem claiming this shows `y[x] == 1` is a solution, when you've used only finitely many terms of the series.

Comment: @MichaelE2 You're totally right, this kind of solution is very hand-wavy and should not be seen as a substitute for a rigorous proof, but more seen as an engineering technique to make the solution that we already suspected more plausible.

Comment: plus usually solutions like `y[x] == 1` here is theoretically easy to check but numerically unstable.